# Foundation 6 Tabs in Accordion

Tags: javascript, tabs, zurb-foundation, accordion

Is it possible with Foundation 6 to put links to tabs (`.tab-title`) within a vertical accordion menu?

My attempt: https://codepen.io/bradleyrcmarques/pen/oePGeX

Additional requirements: if a redirect to this page has an anchor in the URL, the correct tab should be shown, and the accordion expanded to that item.

All examples I can find either deal with turning tabs into an accordion for responsive design, or putting tabs inside an accordion, neither of which are this case.

Comment: I am not exactly clear on what you're trying to do. Do you want to expand the menu or show the content?

I think what you want is http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/accordion-menu.html#down

Comment: Also try this link: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/36914-605---how-to-trigger-accordion-toggle